# Trying to use fetch via js. It's returning as if its not actually calling any data. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm having trouble finding any resources for this. All I need is help in the right direction to get something tangible to use in some HTML. So basically when I call console.log(keys) I don't get the json objects in my console like I'm used to. Project specifically requests it be done this way via fetch.

```js
function getFromSWAPI() {

    fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(data){
        updateInfo(data)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.warn(err)
    })
}

const updateInfo = responseJSON => {
    console.log(responseJSON.data)
    let keys = Object.keys(responseJSON.data)
    console.log(keys)
}
```

Comment: You're calling `updateInfo` with the data object, so `responseJSON` IS the data. So, remove the `.data` after `responseJSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically there is a minor bug in your code,

In this line

```
{...}
.then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
    })
{...}
```

you have already returned the json and thus you are accessing it in the next line

```
{...}
.then(function (data) {
        updateInfo(data)
    })
{...}
```

As the returned data is itself the real data, you don't have to reaccess it with the data property here

```
{...}
const updateInfo = responseJSON => {
    console.log(responseJSON.data)
    let keys = Object.keys(responseJSON.data)
    console.log(keys)
}
```

The finished code will look like this -

```
 function getFromSWAPI() {

    fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(data){
        updateInfo(data)
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.warn(err)
    })
}

const updateInfo = responseJSON => {
    console.log(responseJSON)
    let keys = Object.keys(responseJSON)
    console.log(keys)
}
```

> Alternatively, I would suggest you use async/await if you are using fetch inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with this code; only one of them is the direct cause of the trouble you're having with logging, but they will all need to be fixed before this will work.

**First**: why doesn't console.log work / why are you getting TS error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object at Function.keys"?

Because `responseJSON` does not have a property named "data", because the API response does not include a property named "data". I suspect that name appears here because you're confused by what HTTP responses are and how Promises work. So let's start at the beginning.

`fetch` returns an [HTTP Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object that contains deep within it some text. You access that text by doing:

```js
let text = await response.text()
```

Or, if you're using chained `.then` handlers (as in your sample), you do this:

```js
.then((response) => {
    return response.text()
})
```

If you know that the text is valid JSON (and you do), then you can extract the text *and* parse it into a value with a single operation: `response.json()` (which is what you are doing).

This returns a Promise that contains the value encoded by the JSON. If the value is an object, it'll have the properties described by that JSON.

What properties will your object have? Open that URL in your browser, and you'll see them: "birth_year", "created", "edited", "eye_color", "films", "gender", "hair_color", "height", "homeworld", "mass", "name", "skin_color", "species", "starships", "url", "vehicles".

"data" is not on that list.

This is what you are doing with the info from the response:

```js
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
})
.then(function(data){
    updateInfo(data)
})
```

Thus, you are passing the parsed value directly to the `updateInfo` function.

The `updateInfo` function then tries to log the `.data` property on the received value (which does not exist). That is, `.data` is `undefined`.

It is not an error to log an undefined object. But `Object.keys` will throw if provided with `undefined`:

```js
Object.keys(undefined)
//> Uncaught TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
```

The fix is to remove `.data` from both the log statement and the `Object.keys` call.

**Second:** that should have been your first debugging step. Even without understanding all the above: if operations are failing on datapoints buried within a value, the most obvious first debugging step is to "take a step back" and try to examine the variable you're working with.

To illustrate: if `console.log(myThing.items[0].parent.nodeName)` fails, you should immediately try `console.log(myThing)` -- this allows you to inspect the `myThing` variable so you can manually verify whether the path you're accessing is legitimate. One of the most common mistakes made by devs of all experience levels is that they put in a bad data path, simply because to err is human. (Typescript will help you notice this while you're writing code, but you must learn how to trace problems without the help of a tool, or you will always need that tool.)

**Third:** As I mentioned in the first draft of this post, you're missing some `return` statements.

Most importantly, your `getFromSWAPI` function does not `return` anything. You have to `return` the `fetch` if you want callers to receive the data.

```js
function getFromSWAPI() {
    return fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
    // ...rest of chained thens
```

Also, you need to return *something* inside the `.then` handler where you're calling `updateInfo`. What you return depends on what the purpose of `updateInfo` is:

- if `updateInfo` is supposed to modify the raw API data for the benefit of downstream code, then you should return the result of calling it:

  ```js
  .then(function(data){
      return updateInfo(data)
  })
  ```
- if `updateInfo` is supposed to cause some kind of side-effect (like updating a local cache with the raw data, or firing an event, etc), then you may want to "bypass" the function: call it, but forward the original value to downstream code:

  ```js
  .then(function(data){
      updateInfo(data) // could do _anything_ with data
      return data // passes the original data onward
  })
  ```

---

**Unsolicited code review**

- You're defining one function using the `function` keyword, and defining the other as a const arrow function:

  ```js
  function getFromSWAPI() { /* stuff */ }
  const updateInfo = responseJSON => { /* stuff */ }
  ```

  Both patterns work fine, but you should try to be consistent. My advice: if you're still learning JS, prefer the `function` keyword, because it's more explicit.
- Prefer to use async/await instead of chained handlers

  You can define functions as `async` and then `await` *only* the specific operations that are asynchronous. In your case, `updateInfo` does not appear to do any async work, so it kind of sucks that it has to live inside this three-part chained promise. I'd go with this:

  ```js
  async function getFromSWAPI() {
      let response = await fetch("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1")
      let data = await response.json()
      updateInfo(data)
      return data
  }
  ```

Comment: starwars.js:24 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at updateInfo (starwars.js:32:23)
    at starwars.js:21:16
(anonymous) @ starwars.js:24
Promise.catch (async)
getFromSWAPI @ starwars.js:23

this is what i get running it like that

Comment: This is not the issue in this case. The question asks why the `console.log` calls in the callbacks don't log the data the questioner expects.